# What is the difference between ar/nm and gcc-ar/gcc-nm?

Tags: gcc, binutils, linux-toolchain

`ar`, `nm`, and `ranlib` are provided by the binutils package. `gcc-ar`, `gcc-nm`, and `gcc-ranlib` are provided by the GCC package. I read somewhere that the `gcc-ar`, `gcc-nm`, and `gcc-ranlib` are "effectively wrappers" around the `ar`, `nm`, and `ranlib` binaries respectively.

What is the technical difference between the `gcc-ar`, `gcc-nm`, and `gcc-ranlib` vs. `ar`, `nm`, and `ranlib`? There must be a reason why GCC provides these binaries in its builds.

When should a build system of a userland package use one vs. the other? If the toolchain being used to build a userland package is GCC based, does it matter which one you use (e.g., `ar` vs `gcc-ar`, `nm` vs `gcc-nm`)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`gcc-ar` is a wrapper for GNU `ar` such that a command:

```
gcc-ar ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
ar --plugin=/path/to/liblto_plugin.so ...
```

On my present system, Ubuntu 17.10, GCC 7.2, that would be e.g:

```
ar --plugin=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/liblto_plugin.so
```

There is just the same relationship between `nm` and `gcc-nm`.

The `--plugin` option of the binutils `ar` and `nm` enables them to dynamically
load a recognizer/analyser for some non-default format of object file that
they have to deal with.

The shared library `liblto_plugin.so` is one that enables them to deal with the
IR (*intermediate representation*) object files produced and consumed in link-time-optimized
builds.

So, if you would do your plain old build like this:

```
$ gcc -c main.c foo.c bar.c
$ ar cr libfoobar.a foo.o bar.o
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoobar
```

then you'd do your link-time-optimized build like:

```
$ gcc -flto -c main.c foo.c bar.c
$ gcc-ar cr libfoobar.a foo.o bar.o
$ gcc -flto -o prog main.o -L. -lfoobar
```

In recent releases of `binutils` - I don't know which was the first; within the
last 3 or 4 years - `liblto_plugin.so` has been loaded by default by `ar`
and `nm`; so in fact:

```
$ gcc -flto -c main.c foo.c bar.c
$ ar cr libfoobar.a foo.o bar.o
$ gcc -flto -o prog main.o -L. -lfoobar
```

will work fine; and `nm foo.o` will work fine. But the `gcc-*` versions still serve a purpose in being
independently shipped with GCC, since your regular `ar` and `nm` might not
support that default, and if not then that last build, for instance,
would fail in the linkage with undefined references, since `ar` would fail
to insert in the archive a true symbol table for `foo.o` and `bar.o`.